# How to install JTS in Solr 4?

Tags: solr, jts

Using the Solr 4 spatial field types seems to require an external library, the [Java Topology Suite](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html). How does one install this suite for use with Solr 4.1.0 on Ubuntu Server 12.04 with Java 1.6.0_24?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running Solr in Tomcat on your Ubuntu Server and have deployed the Solr WAR into your `<path to Tomcat>/webapps` folder. Then according to the [Lucene / Solr 4 Spatial](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4#JTS_.2BAC8_WKT_.2BAC8_Polygon_notes) documentation on the Solr Wiki, you just need to copy the all the jar files from the JTS distribution `/lib` folder to the `WEB-INF/lib` folder where Solr is running.

**Update**

Since you are using Jetty to run Solr, you will need to include the location of the JTS jar files as a classpath. Based on the [Classloading Jetty](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Classloading) documentation, something like the following should work:

```
 java -Dsolr.solr.home=/mnt/SolrFiles/solr 
   -Djetty.class.path=<insert path to JTS here> -jar /opt/solr-4.1.0/example/start.jar
```

Comment: Thank you. I am running Solr from `/opt/solr-4.1.0/` with the command `java -Dsolr.solr.home=/mnt/SolrFiles/solr -jar /opt/solr-4.1.0/example/start.jar`.

Comment: Could you please provide a link to download the jts jar file for solr 
    6.6.6?

Comment: Any idea where to put the jts plugin for a cloud environment like platform sh ?

Comment: no main manifest attribute in jts-1.14.jar

Answer (score 3):

The JTS JAR file needs to be placed in the Solr web application's [WEB-INF/lib folder](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4#Configuration). Otherwise you may  encounter a `NoClassDefFoundError: com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry` when starting Solr.

Comment: I'd really like to know what this "combination of things" mentioned on the Wiki is, but have no time to investigate right now...

Comment: Could you please provide a link to download the jts jar file for solr 
    6.6.6?