# Solr 4 spatial class not found com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry

Tags: solr, solr4

I'm running Solr 4.2.1 but I have the exception in my log file `NoClassDefFoundError: com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry`. I've checked similar questions, like [How to install JTS in Solr 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982782/how-to-install-jts-in-solr-4) but that didn't solve the problem.

Listing the content of the solr.war I have the jts library in the correct path

```
WEB-INF/lib/jts-1.8.jar
```

Yet that doesn't solve my problem. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add also:

lib\jtsio-1.x.jar

lib\jdom.jar

lib\acme.jar

Comment: Could you please provide a link to download the jts jar file for solr 
    6.6.6?